# PC to Android Architecture choice: Bluetooth X Wi-fi

Tags: android, architecture, bluetooth, wifimanager, wifi-direct

I have a need: Build a system that allows a offline terminal(it´s a PC) to connect to a server. to do this, we decided to upload the data to a android 3G smartphone and, by network, send the data to the server, retrieve the response and send to terminal. See the scheme below:

GOING
TERMINAL --(?)--> Android App --(HTTP)--> Server

BACK
Server -- (HTTP) --> Android App --(?)--> Terminal

We have some constraints:

1 - The terminal becomes locked until the android send the response from server (It´s a sync message)
2 - We have only text content.
3 - The place where the terminal is connected does not have network signal.
4 - We have to provide a minimum security level possible.
5 - The terminal app will be developed using PHP.

So, my question is: i have to connect the terminal to pc to send and retrieve information from a android phone. Should i use bluetooth or build a wi-fi network (with android phone built-in feature) to connect them?

Did someone have this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use Bluetooth, because it's easier create a client-server app with bluetooth than develop a "Wi-fi point" programatically and the bluetooth dongle is cheaper than a wi-fi module in old computers.